# hide action bar of main activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I want to hide action bar of only one activity - *main activity* .

**I am extending AppCompatActivity. For some reasons I don't want to change it to ActionBar**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

I've tried u`sing getActionBar()` , `getSupportActionBar()` methods but all of them are giving NPE(`NullPointerException`). That is because of using `AppCompatActivity` that removes the native compatibility of actionbar methods.

**Is there a way to hide the action bar from only the main activity screen without extending to ActionBar ??**

Comment: try to use `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` in the AndroidManifest file for this Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use different themes in defferent activities. `theme` is the attribute, which you can set not only in `<application>` tag, but also in `<activity>`.

It the theme where you want to get rid of actionbar, you can use these

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```